# Need to remove UTF-8 special characters while mapping to the xml as a request

Tags: regex, special-characters

We are giving the below description. However, after mapping the data to the XML and printing it, we could see some UTF-8 characters getting mapped to the XML.
Would like to know how to remove these characters - ”

Any apt regular expression for the below would be really helpful.

```
Cycle 1_ Sc17_ Claim By SIT Team_ Please Do not Touch.

<tns:claimDescription xmlns:tns="http://schema.amfam.com/claimCorrespondence">Cycle 1_ Sc17_ Claim By SIT Team_ Please Do not Touch&#8221;.</tns:claimDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may leave only US-ASCII characters in range of `0–127`:

```
[\x00-\x7F]+
```

See demo here: https://regex101.com/r/5iKQLA/1